# When I try to compile and run the MAUI project, I get an APT2000 error

Tags: c#, android, android-emulator, maui

I am in the process of developing my mobile application on MAUI. I've recently finished some of the development on my home PC, and I uploaded the project to the GitHub repository.
After some time, I decided to continue working on the project on my laptop. My laptop was not configured for android emulation, so I did everything as per the tutorial: enabled Hyper-V components, in the Visual Studio 2022 Tools tab -> Android -> Android SDK Manager. After opening the Android SDK Manager, I installed the following components (screenshot 1):
[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9xEB.png)
(I apologize for most of the interface being Russian, but I will try to translate it when necessary)

After installing the emulator, I proceeded to set up the device that I will emulate. I chose the default option, i.e. Pixel 5 on Android 13. I didn't change anything in its settings.
After installing this image, I decided to run the project, but I was constantly getting APT2000 error, even if I connected my phone via USB.

I tried reinstalling the Android emulator and also reinstalling the emulated device. I tried uninstalling and downloading the project from GitHub and launching it. I tried running the project and emulating it through my Android phone.

I expected that the project would start (i.e. it opens the application on the emulated device and displays the interface and application logic), but it did not work.

Comment: Did this error appear when you created a new project?

Comment: @Liyun. Yes, this error persists even when creating a new, empty MAUI project and trying to run it

Comment: Is it APT200 error or APT2000 error and did it build failed or deploy faild?

Comment: According to this issue about [Android - APT2000 build error when project path contains non-ASCII symbols](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5957), please make sure your maui project path has no non-ASCII symbols.

Comment: @Liyun. This is an APT2000 error, I apologize, I made a typo.
I also looked at my project path, it does not contain any non ASCII characters. Here's what it looks like: "C:\Users\MyUserName\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\MyAppName".

Regarding the build or deploy failed question, the error window just gives me this:
"Error APT2000 Cannot find the specified file. (2). -> MyAppName -> C:\Program Files\dotnet\packs\Microsoft.Android.Sdk.Windows\33.0.46\tools\Xamarin.Android.Aapt2.targets -> 212"

Comment: All right. But I can't reproduce your problem and all the threads which had the same error as yours are caused by the path's non ASCII characters. Can you create a new project which path only contains English letters to test again?

Comment: @Liyun. Unfortunately, the problem still persists...

Comment: I reproduced the APT2000 error with the path contained Chinese characters just now. Did your project worked on windows and iOS platforms?

Comment: @Liyun. No, I mean, I don't have a Mac to test on iOS, and I did the application itself right under Android, which is why I didn't install the necessary components for testing on Windows

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem in my pc. I can only reproduce the APT2000 error with the method above. You can post an new issue on the github.

Comment: @Liyun. Okay, I'll try. In any case, thanks for the help, maybe someone else will see my problem and offer their solution, time will tell. I think I'm not the only one with such a problem

Comment: All right, and if you resolve your problem. You can share the solution here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by posting an issue on GitHub in the official MAUI repository. You can read the full answer [here](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/16081).

In short, it was because my projects folder had the path `C:\Users\MyUserName\OneDrive\Desktop\Projects\MyAppName`. As you may have noticed, my desktop is located in the OneDrive folder. Moving the Projects folder to the root of my C drive solved the problem and my project started. Apparently this is somehow related to [another issue](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/issues/6925) about the project path containing non-ASCII characters, at least that's what I was told in the response to my issue on GitHub.

To summarize: check your project path, and if you get the same error, try moving the projects folder to the root of your C drive, and run the project from there.